# Automate the css versioning in smarty(2.6)

Tags: css, smarty, versioning, smarty2

I need to force `CSS` changes to go live immediately and I found that add a version to `CSS` would help to do that as bellow.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?version=123456" media="all"/>
```

I need to automate this as it is difficult to change the main file always when need to do small change to css file.

So I found following line of code(sample) in `PHP` doing the same job.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); echo '?' . filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
```

I have tried to convert this line to `Smarty`, but it is giving error.

code :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?version={@filemtime:css/style.css} />
```

error:

```
syntax error: unrecognized tag: @filemtime:...........
```

Anybody has an idea how to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this modifier to smarty plugin folder,

```
function smarty_modifier_filemtime($path){
    $path = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
    return filemtime( YOUR_HOME_DIR.$path );
}
```

then call it like bellow,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css?v={'/css/style.css'|@filemtime}" type="text/css">
```